Does Terraform allow dynamic references in the backend block?
I'm using Terraform 1.9.4 and in my setup i want each of my env (DEV/UAT/PROD) to have it's own backend (S3) and this is how it is defined:
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "my-terraform-state-bucket"
    key            = "env/${terraform.workspace}/terraform.tfstate" 
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "my-terraform-locks"
 }
}

after running Terraform init i get:
   Error: Variables not allowed

   on backend.tf line 4, in terraform:

I'd appreciate any tips on this  -- I prefer not to define a bakend.tf for each env :(

No it does not.
An alternative is to pass the config via CLI like this:
# backend.hcl
bucket         = "my-terraform-state-bucket"
region         = "us-east-1"
dynamodb_table = "my-terraform-locks"
encrypt        = true

And then call it:
$ terraform init -backend-config=backend.hcl

By doing this you can take what's common between files and extract it.
Terraform will merge the config so you still need to declare the backend block.
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key = "env/prod/terraform.tfstate" 
 }
}

